# How to close a single JetBrains IDE on Mac?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, goland

I usually have many JetBrains IDE's opened (let's say WebStorm).

If I try and close one of them, all of the other automatically close.

How can I close a single IDE on Mac, instead of closing all of them?

Both closing button (red dot) and <kbd>Command+Q</kbd> seems to have the same effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a single instance of the IDE running with multiple project windows open.

Use File | Close Project or assign a keyboard shortcut to this action in the IDE Prefrences | Keymap.